# Hi, I have this code with missing Criteria

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[![First output][1]][1]

[![Second output][2]][2]

[![Combined Output][3]][3]

[![Combined Script][4]][4]

I have this code, but the Criteria in "R" (LN-5360) do not exist. However, the criteria in "S" does exist with a sum value of '30'. But when I join both queries it is giving me the "MonthlyPremium" as '0' instead of '30'. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I can't remove "R" because I have more existing criteria.

```sql
Select S.Newf, zeroifnull(Round(PR + PRE)) AS MonthlyPremium  

From
(  
SELECT TARGET_QUIKPLANSurv.FORM, Ifnull(TARGET_NEWQUIKVALFSurDec.MVALDATE, '2020-12-31') AS ReportDate ,(SUM(TARGET_NEWQUIKVALFSurDec.MANNLZD)/12) AS PR
from TARGET_QUIKPLANSurv Left JOIN TARGET_NEWQUIKVALFSurDec ON TARGET_QUIKPLANSurv.PLAN=TARGET_NEWQUIKVALFSurDec.NPLAN
GROUP BY TARGET_QUIKPLANSurv.FORM, TARGET_NEWQUIKVALFSurDec.MVALDATE
HAVING ((TARGET_QUIKPLANSurv.FORM)='LN-5360')
                
) as R

Right Join

( 
SELECT TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS, Ifnull(TARGET_NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE, '2020-12-31') AS ReportDate ,(SUM(TARGET_NEWQUIKVALF1.MANNLZD)/12) AS PRE,
     iff(TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS='L-5360','LN-5360', TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS ) As Newf  
   
from TARGET_QUIKPLAN Left JOIN TARGET_NEWQUIKVALF1 ON TARGET_QUIKPLAN.PLAN=TARGET_NEWQUIKVALF1.NPLAN
GROUP BY TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS, TARGET_NEWQUIKVALF1.MVALDATE
HAVING ((TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='L-5360')  
         
) as S on R.FORM = S.Newf 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L0MO.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkPca.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO1uX.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFJYS.png
```

Comment: Again, can you post some example data and the expect output. You are writing SQL that looks wrong, BUT you might be correct, because your data is crazy. But it REALLY hard to help without the sample data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. We would love to help you @Dgbow, but there's not enough information to reproduce.

Comment: I Just upload the full data on a different post.

Comment: I have also shared the data in this post

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a value on the S (of 30 as you note) side, and you are doing a RIGHT JOIN you have a row. Time to learn how the different operations you are using work and thus where does the 0 comes from:

```
SELECT pr
    ,pre
    ,pr + pre AS a
    ,round(a) AS ra
    ,ZEROIFNULL(ra) as monthlypremium
FROM VALUES 
    (0,30),   
    (null,30),
    (0,null),
    (null,null)
    v(pr,pre);
```

so this is 4 rows of data, with different permutations of results, really the last would not happen.

```
PR      PRE     A       RA      MONTHLYPREMIUM
0       30      30      30      30
null    30      null    null    0
0       null    null    null    0
null    null    null    null    0
```

So this tells us addition with a `null` is null, therefore you need to move the ZEROIFNULL to prior of the addition. Thus you want:

```
ROUND(ZEROIFNULL(pr) + ZEROIFNULL(pre)) AS monthlypremium
```

As a side note putting your SQL select on new lines makes it easier to read on StackOverflow, and using aliases for your tables, makes reading faster, and given case of columns does not matter, having reserve words and column different case helps comprehension also. I also tend to indent ON and follow WHERE clauses just so you can wrap things onto new lines to keep the reading width not to wide, and follow this is more of the last block of logic.

Thus I would write your SQL for style:

```
select s.newf
    ,ROUND(ZEROIFNULL(pr) + ZEROIFNULL(pre)) AS monthlypremium
FROM (  
    SELECT q.form
        ,IFNULL(n.mvaldate, '2020-12-31') AS reportdate 
        ,SUM(n.mannlzd)/12 AS pr
    FROM target_quikplansurv AS q
    LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalfsurdec AS n
        ON q.plan = n.nplan
    GROUP BY q.form, n.mvaldate
    HAVING q.form='LN-5360'              
) AS r
RIGHT JOIN ( 
    SELECT q.forms
        ,ifnull(n.mvaldate, '2020-12-31') AS reportdate
        ,SUM(n.mannlzd)/12 AS pre
        ,iff(q.forms = 'L-5360', 'LN-5360', q.forms ) AS newf   
    FROM target_quikplan AS q
    LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalf1 AS n
        ON q.plan = n.nplan
    GROUP BY q.forms, n.mvaldate
    HAVING q.forms = 'L-5360'    
) AS s 
    ON r.form = s.newf
```

Lastly what the SQL is doing

```
    SELECT q.form
        ,IFNULL(n.mvaldate, '2020-12-31') AS reportdate 
        ,SUM(n.mannlzd)/12 AS pr
    FROM target_quikplansurv AS q
    LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalfsurdec AS n
        ON q.plan = n.nplan
    GROUP BY q.form, n.mvaldate
    HAVING q.form='LN-5360'
```

here you are grouping by the original source table `mvaldate`, but you are converting to a default ('2020-12-31') in the select, thus you are pointing out `mvaldate` can be null, but by group on the original the input

```
FORM,       mvaldate,     mannlzd
'LN-5360',  '2020-11-30', 120
'LN-5360',  '2020-12-31', 240
'LN-5360',  null,         360
```

would give the output:

```
'LN-5360',  '2020-11-30', 10
'LN-5360',  '2020-12-31', 20
'LN-5360',  '2020-12-31', 30
```

because the third row NULL is different to second row '2020-12-31'. Maybe you want that. But I suspect that would make people puzzled

But also by having the `HAVING` clause all the aggregation will occur. If you have 10 million rows with `form` being different to 'LN-3560' those values will all get calculated, and thrown away, which would imply you should swap to a WHERE clause, as you might be able to avoid data read (due to micro partitioning) and avoid the aggregation.

which makes me think you really want your SQL to look like:

```
SELECT s.newf
    ,ROUND(ZEROIFNULL(pr) + ZEROIFNULL(pre)) AS monthlypremium
FROM (  
    SELECT q.form
        ,IFNULL(n.mvaldate, '2020-12-31') AS reportdate 
        ,SUM(n.mannlzd)/12 AS pr
    FROM target_quikplansurv AS q
    LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalfsurdec AS n
        ON q.plan = n.nplan
    WHERE q.form='LN-5360'   
    GROUP BY 1,2   
) AS r
RIGHT JOIN ( 
    SELECT q.forms
        ,ifnull(n.mvaldate, '2020-12-31') AS reportdate
        ,SUM(n.mannlzd)/12 AS pre
        ,iff(q.forms = 'L-5360', 'LN-5360', q.forms ) AS newf   
    FROM target_quikplan AS q
    LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalf1 AS n
        ON q.plan = n.nplan
    WHERE q.forms = 'L-5360'
    GROUP BY 1,2
) AS s 
    ON r.form = s.newf
```

But given your code as written it could also be:

```
SELECT s.newf
    ,ROUND(ZEROIFNULL(pr) + ZEROIFNULL(pre)) AS monthlypremium
FROM (  
    SELECT q.form
        ,IFNULL(n.mvaldate, '2020-12-31') AS reportdate 
        ,SUM(n.mannlzd)/12 AS pr
    FROM target_quikplansurv AS q
    LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalfsurdec AS n
        ON q.plan = n.nplan
    WHERE q.form='LN-5360'   
    GROUP BY 1,2          
) AS r
RIGHT JOIN ( 
    SELECT q.forms
        ,IFNULL(n.mvaldate, '2020-12-31') AS reportdate
        ,SUM(n.mannlzd)/12 AS pre
        ,'LN-5360' AS newf   
    FROM target_quikplan AS q
    LEFT JOIN target_newquikvalf1 AS n
        ON q.plan = n.nplan
    WHERE q.forms = 'L-5360'
    GROUP BY 1,2     
) AS s 
    ON r.form = s.newf
```