# Can I add two subqueries when one query has missing criteria?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: Combined SCript]
[image: First Output]

[image: Second Output]

[image: Combined output]

Hi guys,
I hope you all are doing well. I am having this issue, and I hope you guys can help me out.
From the photos attached, I have created two subqueries. "First output" contains the variables with all the criteria. "Second output" contains only seven criteria. My hope is when adding (PRE + PR), it will return 132.77, 1021.59, and 8.03 respectively from "PRE" instead of NULLS. (See combined Output).
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong from the Combined Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the same problem I answered yesterday.

```
ZEROIFNULL(PR) + ZEROIFNULL(PRE)
```

[Yesterdays answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752893/hi-i-have-this-code-with-missing-criteria), with full explanation of what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, Simeon. I did an If statement to get it to work, but your way works too. Thank you so much

Comment: @dgbow understood, `iff(pr is null,0,pr)` or iff(pr is not null,pr,0)` are 20 or 24 characters verse 14, and have a slightly higher comprehension cost to a reader. But also you had already show previously that you knew about ZEROIFNULL, anyways. Glad to hear you have learn that null don't sum (outside of a aggregation functions (sum/avg/count) where they are ignored)